# Django IntegrityError at /main/addcomment/1 NOT NULL constraint failed: main_comment.post_id

Tags: django, python-3.x

I stuck by an integrity error when I passed comment to my product review page. Help Me through this.
I think the error occurs because of the args which passed through the render function.

My models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
post = models.ForeignKey(List, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
subject = models.CharField(max_length=200)
text = models.TextField()
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.user)
```

views.py

```
def addcomment(request, id):
list = get_object_or_404(List, pk=id)
form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    data = Comment()
    data.subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
    data.text = form.cleaned_data['text']
    print("Redirected.....")
    current_user = request.user
    data.user_id = current_user.id
    data.save()
    messages.success(request, "Your Comment has been sent. Thank you for your interest.")
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main:hackathonList', args=[list.id]))
return render(request, 'product.html', {'list': list, 'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Comment
    fields = ('subject', 'text')
```

urls.py

```
    path('addcomment/<int:id>', views.addcomment, name='addcomment'),
```

template.html

```
<form action="{% url 'main:addcomment' user.id %}" role="form" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>{{ form | crispy }}</p>
        {% if user.id is not none %}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Comment</button>
        {% else %}
            You must be logged in to post a review.
        {% endif %}
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In views.py instead of `data.user_id = current_user.id` ie remove this line and add int its place

> data.user = current_user 
>   data.post = list

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```html
<form action="{% url 'main:addcomment' list.id %}" role="form" method="post">
```

this first. After that, just add a new line before save method call like:
`data.post = list`

Comment: You have `post` in your template right? Maybe you pass the name `list`, if so, change `post.id` with `list.id` The purpose here to pass the post's pk to view correctly.

Comment: It is great to hear that. I have also updated my answer to be acceptable.